# Implementation of Servlet with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsp, servlets

> I want to develop an application using Servlet, JSP, Core java, Hibernate.
>
> How can i implement servlet with Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please hava a look on this one

http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/hibernate-in-servlet-example-hibernate-in-servlet-tutorial/